# Visualforce charting- Line chart

Tags: visualforce-charting

I have created a VF chart to display a Line chart with 2 data series. Now I have written 2 differnt methods in order to fetch the data from 2 different unrelated objects. In order to call these 2 methods in data attribute of , I have created page reference method and called these 2 methods. Now when Im trying to call this page reference method in my VF page, its giving an error `Unknown property 'MyController.mastermethod`. Please suggest.

Controller-

```
 public PageReference masterMethod() {   
 getLineData();
 getLineData1();  
 return null;
}

//Method 1

 public List<LineChartData> getLineData() 
{  
    List<LineChartData> ldata = new List<LineChartData>();
    List<Profile__c> pv = new List<Profile__c>();        
    String sql = 'SELECT Name, Profile_Value__c, Date__c FROM Profile__c';
    pv = Database.Query(sql);
    for(Profile__c temp: pv)
    {
    if(temp.Profile_Value__c !=null && temp.Date__c !=null)       
    {           
        ldata.add(new LineChartData(temp.Date__c, temp.Profile_Value__c));           
    }
  }
    return ldata;  
}  

// Wrapper class  
public class LineChartData
{  
    public Date Date1 { get; set; }  
    public Decimal Profile { get; set; }        
    public LineChartData(Date Date1, Decimal Profile) 
    {  
        this.Date1 = Date1;  
        this.Profile = Profile;              
    }  
}



//Method 2
public List<LineChartData1> getLineData1() 
{  
    List<LineChartData1> ldata1 = new List<LineChartData1>();      
    List<Contact> cont1 = new List<Contact>();  


    String sql = 'SELECT id, Name, Date__c, Market_Value__c FROM Contact WHERE id= :selectedName';        
    cont1 = Database.Query(sql);
    for(Contact temp: cont1)
    {
    if(temp.Market_Value__c !=null && temp.Date__c !=null)       
    {           
        ldata1.add(new LineChartData1(temp.Date__c, temp.Market_Value__c));           
    }
  }
    return ldata1;  
}  

// Wrapper class  
public class LineChartData1
{  
    public Date Date2 { get; set; }         
    public Decimal MarketValue { get; set; }  

    public LineChartData1(Date Date2, Decimal MarketValue ) 
    {  
        this.Date2 = Date2;             
        this.MarketValue  = MarketValue ;  
    }
```

VF Page-

```
<apex:outputPanel id="LineData"  style="width:100%; ">
<apex:pageblock id="Graph" title="Performance" >
    <apex:chart height="300" width="500" data="{!mastermethod}">       
        <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="Profile,MarketValue"
        grid="true"/>            
        <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="Date1">            
        </apex:axis>
        <apex:lineSeries axis="left" fill="true" xField="Date1" yField="Profile"
        markerType="cross" markerSize="4" markerFill="#FF0000"/>
        <apex:lineSeries axis="left" xField="Date1" yField="MarketValue"
        markerType="circle" markerSize="4" markerFill="#8E35EF"/>
        <apex:legend position="right"/>           
    </apex:chart>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:outPutPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

The chart `data` attribute should reference a property that returns data not a method that returns null. The values for both series need to be represented by one object:

```
public class CombinedLineChartData implements Comparable {  
    public Date Datex { get; set; }  
    public Decimal Profile { get; set; }  
    public Decimal MarketValue { get; set; }
    public Integer compareTo(Object o) {
        CombinedLineChartData that = (CombinedLineChartData) o;
        if (that.Datex < this.Datex) return -1;
        else if (that.Datex> this.Datex) return 0;
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

and your logic in the property getter will need to merge the two queries into one list of objects:

```
public List<CombinedLineChartData> getCombinedLineData() {
    Map<Date, CombinedLineChartData> m = new Map<Date, CombinedLineChartData>();
    for (Profile__c p : [
           SELECT Date__c, Profile_Value__c
           FROM Profile__c
           WHERE Date__c != null
           AND Profile_Value__c != null
           ]) {
       CombinedLineChartData d = m.get(p.Date__c);
       if (d == null) {
           d = new CombinedLineChartData();
           d.Datex = p.Date__c;
           m.put(p.Date__c, d);
       }
       d.Profile = p.Profile_Value__c;
    }
    for (Contact c : [
           SELECT Date__c, Market_Value__c
           FROM Contact
           WHERE id= :selectedName
           AND Date__c != null
           AND Market_Value__c != null
           ]) {
       CombinedLineChartData d = m.get(c.Date__c);
       if (d == null) {
           d = new CombinedLineChartData();
           d.Datex = c.Date__c;
           m.put(c.Date__c, d);
       }
       d.MarketValue = c.Market_Value__c;
    }
    // Chart probably needs entries on order so sort
    List<CombinedLineChartData> l = m.values();
    l.sort();
    return l;
}
```

See [Building a Complex Chart with Visualforce Charting](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_charting_example.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I tried your suggestion, but its not working. Could you please help me with giving an idea on how to apply the same with my code.

Comment: @SalesforceLearner I've added code for how I would merge the data if that is the part you are asking about.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs. I tried your code, but it gave error. I removed others but got stuck at this one: "Variable does not exist: Date at line d.Date = p.Date__c;"  Although this already has been defined.

Comment: @SalesforceLearner Yeah sorry about that. Try the code as posted now.